# Clone of state with id is changed when state is changed

Tags: reactjs

I change my data on the fly. I want to keep a snapshot of what was my state at first rendering of my application in order to compare it with updated state at the end. 
It is an array of objects and mongoose generates an  _id, which I use.

On componentDidMount I store my state in a variable.

```
let test;
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.fetchGeneral(_id).then(() => {
           test = this.props.general.cars;
        }).catch(() => {
          console.error(this.props.errors);
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({redirect: true, url: '/'});
    }
  };
```

If I change my state like this :

```
this.setState({cars : newValue }) //I update the whole object
```

or like this :

```
this.setState({...cars : newValue })
```

It will ALSO update my variable **test**

... I think it's because of my "_id", I don't know why. Is there a way to make a snapshot of my state at rendering of my app ?

example of my object :

> "car":{"owner":[{"_id":"5b7af38a5b302729506b5e4b","value":"REYNOLDS
>   ryan","label":"REYNOLDS
>   ryan"}],"_id":"5b7af3895b302729506b5e42","carBrand":"Hyundai","carColor":"blue","carPlate":"AA-BB-CC"}}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @any-moose I searched around objects' cloning and it turns out that each object has a reference so you have to use deep cloning to not copy that reference.

Here's the two methods that worked for me :

JAVASCRIPT:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.general.cars))
```

LODASH :

```
_.cloneDeep(this.props.general.cars);
```

Comment: Nice, glad you found it... I'm sure others will run into this issue too...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Object.Assign

```
let newObject = Object.assign({}, this.state.object);
```

So in your code

```
let test;
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.fetchGeneral(_id).then(() => {
           test = Object.assign({}, this.props.general.cars);
        }).catch(() => {
          console.error(this.props.errors);
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({redirect: true, url: '/'});
    }
  };
```

Comment: Good thought but that doesn't work either. This is really strange, I'm not sure why react state has to deal with an object _id if don't mention it